# Google Maps API coordinates from WordPress custom post type

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been having some issues getting the Google Maps API V3 to work when getting the latitude and longitude from a custom post type.  I previously had it working when pulling data directly in from a separate database.  However, when changing this to pull data in from a post type using WP_Query, the Google Maps API doesn't display the map markers as it doesn't seem to accept the format (I assume).

Here is the code I use to pull the data from the post type and store in a PHP array:

```
 $args = array (
  'post_type'              => array( 'card' ),
  'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
);

// The Query
$site_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$result = array();
// The Loop
if ( $site_query->have_posts() ) {

  while ( $site_query->have_posts() ) {
    $site_query->the_post();
    $sitename = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'siteName', true );
    $addr1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'addr1', true );
    $addr2 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'addr2', true );
    $op1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'op1', true );
    $priceclass = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price_class', true );
    $longitude = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'longitude', true );
    $latitude = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'latitude', true );


     $result[] = array(
       'siteName' => $sitename,
       'addr1' => $addr1,
       'addr2' => $addr2,
       'op1' => $op1,
       'price_class' => $priceclass,
       'longitude' => $latitude,
       'latitude' => $latitude,
     );

  }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

I then store this in a JavaScript variable:

```
    var locations = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
```

A console log shows that this data gets here as intended and is stored as an object. I have skipped out the basic Google Maps initalisation, and here is the code which should print markers on the map.

```
 for(var v = 0; v < locations.length; v++) {

                    if(locations[v].op1 == "Open 24 Hours"){

                      console.log(locations[v].latitude);
                      console.log(locations[v].longitude); 


              if (circle.contains(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[v].latitude, locations[v].longitude))) {   


                var marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[v].latitude, locations[v].longitude),
                    map: map,
                    icon: {
                          url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/contact_map_pin1.png',
                          size: new google.maps.Size(40, 50),
                          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                          anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 50)
                    }
                });
                gmarkers.push(marker);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: info_content});

            var info_content = 
                '<div id="content">'+
                '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="iw-title">'+ locations[v].siteName + '</h1>'+
                '<div id="bodyContent">'+ 
                '</div>'+
                '<p class="infobox-address">' + locations[v].addr1 + '<br>' + locations[v].addr2 + '<br>' + locations[v].addr3 + '<br>' + locations[v].postcode + '</p>'+
                '</div>';

                 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', getInfoCallback(map, info_content));


                     jQuery('.locations-section').append('<div class="location-single"><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/'+ locations[v].latitude +','+ locations[v].longitude +'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><h3>'+ locations[v].siteName + '</h3><p>' + locations[v].addr1 + '<br>' + locations[v].addr2 + '<br>' + locations[v].addr3 + '<br>' + locations[v].postcode + '</p></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

              } 

               }

          }
```

The console.log's here show that the correct values of `locations[v].latitude` and `locations[v].longitude` are getting to this point but aren't working with the Google Maps API.

I don't understand why this is working and have tried converting the latitude and longitude to type float in both PHP and JavaScript but nothing seems to work. Can anyone explain what is wrong?

Comment: Check if `if (circle.contains...` is `true`. Check if `url` of `icon` is valid.

Comment: Yes, both worked correctly when pulling the exact same information from a separate database.  When I remove the `if (circle.contains...`, it still doesn't print the markers to the map.